# inner quotation marks in XML file

Tags: sql, xml

i have an XML file of queries that look like this:

```
<queries>
    <query queryType="statement" query="alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true" ignore="false">
        <auditEventVerifications normalizedQuery="alter session set "_oracle_script"=true">
        </auditEventVerifications>
    </query>
.
.
.
```

i want my query to be:
 `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true`

but the inner quotation marks make the file compiles with errors.
how can I mark the inner quotation?

doing this: \ "_ORACLE_SCRIPT\ " didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the query to
query='alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true'
did the work!

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you posted originally?

Comment: I see that you've now edited the `query` attribute to `query="alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true"`.  Right, that wouldn't have worked as it wouldn't have been well-formed XML.